# Djanjo with Rest Framework and Postgres search

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search, django-rest-framework

I need to make search for looking some data from database and this search field should support some logical operations. Like AND, OR, NOT and so on.

So I found that Postgres db has something that I need. Ad Django documentation saying to us we need to use SearchQuery with parameter `search_type='websearch'`
And we have something like

```
SearchQuery("'tomato' ('red' OR 'green')", search_type='websearch')  # websearch operators
```

When I'm tried to implement to my project I did something like that

```
# views.py

class DataSearch(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Data.objects.all()
        query = self.request.query_params.get('query')
        if query is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                search_vector = SearchQuery(
                    query,
                    search_type='websearch'
                )
            )
            
        return queryset
```

But when I'm trying to run it I get

> Cannot resolve keyword 'search_vector' into field. Choices are: data, foo, foo_id

So what I should do to make it work and to make API endpoint for this type of search?

Comment: Can you link the part of Django documentation that tells you to use `SearchQuery` and `search_type='websearch'`?

Comment: yeah, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchquery)

Comment: Right. As with any `filter`, that `search_vector` refers to a field name. If you [haven't added and populated a SearchVectorField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvectorfield) with the name `search_vector`, that's not going to do work.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Tried to do it with vector it's doing something. But now I'm stuck in the point were I need to make it work through multiple models.